# iPhone - UIViewController class dealloc function never called

Tags: iphone, memory, uiviewcontroller, dealloc, iboutlet

I have an issue with a project of mine.

I have a "Menu" UIViewController class and the dealloc function is never called.
Most of the UI was added in Interface Builder and has no IBOutlet.

How can I free the memory if dealloc is not called?

---

I simulated an memory warning and now dealloc function was called.

Here is an example of my code:

```
//first.m
- (void) onButton
{ second *modalView = [[second alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
[modalView release];}
```

So, when I am in second screen and I simulate memory warning should the dealloc from the first class fire?

Anyway, in my application no dealloc is called :(.

Comment: I merged your unregistered account with your registered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try 'Hardware -> Simulate Memory Warning' option in the Simulator to check whether the -dealloc is called.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder caches nibs until there's a memory warning, or it exhausts its cache. At such time, it will reclaim any memory that it was using.

Comment: So I it OK this behavior? Should I worry about it anymore? :D

Comment: Yeah don't worry about it so long as you're following the object ownership rules.

Comment: now everything is back to normal :). Any ideas on why is now working?